# search Input number with string list(similar to t9 dictionary)

Tags: java, c++, c

How does a T9 dictionary work? What is the data structure behind it. For example: There is list/dictionary of 16 words(ALL in capital). You'll give input in numbers and the corresponding output should be word which matches number from dictionary.how to implement this in either C/C++/JAVA.[Also it should support if any word is added to the list]

```
2:A/B/C
3:D/E/F
4:G/H/I
5:J/K/L
6:M/N/O
7:P/Q/R/S
8:T/U/V
9:W/X/Y/Z

LIST{DRAWING,PAINTING,DANCE.....}
```

Example of output window:

```
Input : 3729464
output : DRAWING
```

Comment: Try a *prefix tree*, or "trie".

Comment: @KerrekSB is there any other approach?

Comment: if you want to do sth simple just create list of possible words from your digit string, and then put them against your dictionary

Comment: @SwethaDMurthy You may want to use different tags with your post. If you really want C/C++/Java code, these three tags are appropriate, but you are not likely to get what you want (see e.g. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142870/possible-new-close-reason-overt-request-for-code)). But if your main interest is in algorithmic ideas, perhaps "algorithm" and "string-matching" are appropriate tags.

Answer (score 1):

If a simple direct lookup of complete words is sufficient, best write a function that replaces the characters of a word with their corresponding digits:

```
A,B,C  -> 2
D,E,F  -> 3
```

etc.

Then apply that function to all dictionary entries and store the result as key, but the original form as value of a hash table (or similar data structure). Since each digit can represent more than one distinct character, the same key may have to be mapped to multiple values. You could use a list of strings as value type:

```
entries(3829464)  = [DRAWING]
entries(72468464) = [PAINTING]
entries(843)      = [THE,TIE]
```

and so on.

Then you can search for the given input sequence of digits directly against the keys of the hash and easily retrieve all candidates as a ready-made list.

The actual T9 function supports continuations as well: Enter a sequence of digits, and retrieve all strings that may be possible continuations of the input sequence. For that, a search trie is a good data structure. Again, the digits resulting from character conversions are best used as transition labels of the trie, and the original forms of the strings are best stored in the accepting states. You may want to store additional information in the internal nodes, such as the total number of accepting states found in the subtrie below a given node; this will help you decide in O(1) time whether to start traversing the subtrie to retrieve all continuation candidates, or better wait until more input is given by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer to the question:

Isn't T9 also do something like guessing the word? I assume there is something like a weigthed tree in there, guessing the most likely (three or so) words for the digit sequence entered so far. That would be quite mor then O(1) then.

It seems, that not really needed here, but I'm just curious.